# If a variable only contains one word

Tags: php, variables

I would like to know how I could find out in PHP if a variable only contains 1 word. It should be able to recognise: "foo" "1326" ";394aa", etc.

It would be something like this:

```
$txt = "oneword";

if($txt == 1 word){ do.this; }else{ do.that; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to more clearly define what a "word" is in this context.  What delineates two words from each other?  Clearly ``"two words"`` would be two words, but how about ``"hyphenated-word"``?  What about ``" spaces   "``?

Comment: where id the sord in "1326" or in "394aaa"  the firs is just numbers. in the second there are letter but aaa is not in fact a word

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming a word is defined as any string delimited by one space symbol

```
$txt = "multiple words";

if(strpos(trim($txt), ' ') !== false)
{
    // multiple words
}
else
{
    // one word
}
```

Comment: Possibly also trim the string so that " word" or "word " is not counted

Comment: @danneth But what about if " word" is considered two words? It may seem silly but we can't assume that's unreasonable.

Comment: @kiley-naro I think this is hardly ever the required behavior.

Comment: @gilden Kiley Naro is right, there needs to be a space between two numbers/letters/symbols

Answer (score 4):

What defines one word? Are spaces allowed (perhaps for names)? Are hyphens allowed? Punctuation? Your question is not very clearly defined.

Going under the assumption that you just want to determine whether or not your value contains spaces, try using regular expressions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
<?php
$txt = "oneword";

if (preg_match("/ /", $txt)) {
    echo "Multiple words.";
} else {
    echo "One word.";
}
?>
```

**Edit**
The benefit to using regular expressions is that if you can become proficient in using them, they will solve a lot of your problems and make changing requirements in the future a lot easier. I would strongly recommend using regular expressions over a simple check for the position of a space, both for the complexity of the problem today (as again, perhaps spaces aren't the only way to delimit words in your requirements), as well as for the flexibility of changing requirements in the future.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. " --Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos) function included within PHP.

> Returns the position as an integer. If needle is not found, strpos()
> will return boolean FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Besides strpos, an alternative would be [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

```
$txt = trim("oneword secondword");
$words = explode( " ", $txt); // $words[0] = "oneword", $words[1] = "secondword"

if (count($words) == 1) 
    do this for one word
else
    do that for more than one word assuming at least one word is inputted
```

Comment: this would work but calls two functions whereas in the other examples only strpos is needed

Comment: Very true. The others are more efficient. Although he didn't ask for it, and depending on how he wants to process his multiple words, he could used the exploded array or count as part of his processing.

Comment: no its good to see other ways this is great just wanted to point out that its slightly less efficient.

Comment: @Chase You could speed it up a little by using `if (isset($words[1]))`. A rather pointless micro-optimization, but nevertheless, just wanted to point out.